# Listview with multiple child list

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to develop listview with multiple child like below image, I Google but not got any similar solution.

```
 Job 1
     Floor 1
          Floor 2 
          Floor 3               
                    Room 1
                    Room 2
                    Room 3
 Job 2
        Floor 2
                    Room 2
 Job 3
 Job 4
```

[image]

Can someone suggest me? how to achieve something like, any hint or link?

Comment: Since you tagged `Expandablelistview`. You want the children to appear onClick of respective parent? Or just show a ListView like the one in the image you posted?

Comment: onclick of  of respective parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen and tried this one :

http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Comment: Looks like the perfect thing to me! +1 !

Answer (score 0):

In general ExpandableListView supports only 2-level ListView.

Here is an [Example of 3-level ListView](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html), may be you can add more levels.